# Migrating "slot" deprecated syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm running on vue.js 2.6.1
the current code (written by a co-worker who's not around anymore)

He used the 'scope' directive with the following deprecated syntax

```
<template slot="HEAD[epc]" slot-scope="data">
            <div>
              <p class="column-title">{{data.label}}</p>
              <p class="explanation-text">{{data.field.explanation}}</p>
            </div>
</template>
```

I want to access the slot-scope "data" prop
but I want to migrate the old syntax onto a new one
the documentation fails to explain how.

also, I tried changing the scope="head[epc]" to v-slot and the console warns me of mixed syntax.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You'd want something like `v-slot:HEAD[epc]="data"` but I'm not entirely sure you can do that. I've never seen dynamic names like that used in a `slot` attribute so I'm not entirely sure what it's referring to

Comment: Any chance you could show the `<slot>` tag for the component. I can't wrap my head around what `HEAD[epc]` is meant to match

Comment: have you tried this
```
  <template v-slot:HEAD[epc]="data">
    
```

Comment: If `HEAD[epc]` is a literal slot name within the child component, I'd get that changed ASAP. It's just confusing and causes issues with trying to use the newer syntax.

Comment: v-slot:HEAD[epc]="data" was the sollution.
I've got a prop that get injected in so a dynamic slot name is is what I needed, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess that `HEAD[epc]` is a literal slot name within your child component, eg

```html
<slot name="HEAD[epc]" :label="label" :field="field"></slot>
```

In order to use this, you will need to create a `data` or `computed` property to represent it and use the [dynamic slot name syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names). For example, in your parent component

```html
<template v-slot:[slotname]="data">
```

```js
data: () => ({
  slotname: 'HEAD[epc]'
})
```

```js
Vue.component('Test', {
  data: () => ({
    label: 'Label',
    field: {
      explanation: 'Explanation'
    }
  }),
  template: `<div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <slot name="HEAD[epc]" :label="label" :field="field"></slot>
  </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    slotname: 'HEAD[epc]'
  })
})
```

```css
.column-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.explanation-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test>
    <template v-slot:[slotname]="data">
    <div>
      <p class="column-title">{{data.label}}</p>
      <p class="explanation-text">{{data.field.explanation}}</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  </test>
</div>
```

Comment: This was it, 
```
<template v-slot:[slotname]="data">
```
thanks.
the issue is that I do have many slot names inside my parrent. SO a dynamic slot name was my sollution. thanks