# Migrating "slot" deprecated syntax - slot name containing uppercase letters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, migration

I am migrating vue v2.6.11 from v2.5.16. I have a problem with migrating "slot" syntax. What I want to achieve in new way is:

```js
<template slot="TABLE_CELL_actions" slot-scope="scope">
    ...template body
</template>
```

I was trying a lot of combinations also reading [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) but none of it works after vue update.
I tried also [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057405/migrating-slot-deprecated-syntax):

```
<template v-slot:[slotname]="scope">
   ...
</template>
```

with

```
data: function () {
    return {
        slotname: "TABLE_CELL_actions"
    }
}
```

unfortunately without effect.

**Has anyone idea to solve slot name containing upper case letters?**

**@Edit**

> Okay, for now I am sure that issue depends on vue version.

As you can see on v2.5.16  the template properly shows buttons in a table 
[image: well working template slot]
and it not working in v2.6.11
[image]

To test both i used the same below posted code with vue data as posted above.

```html
<vulf-data-table :item-request="request" :fields="fields" ref="dt">
    <template v-slot:[slotname]="scope">
        <a :href="'@FormUrl'+scope.item.id" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"><i class="oi oi-eye"></i></a>
    </template>
</vulf-data-table>
```

I also suppose that the template itself is well recognized because `Object.keys(this.$scopedSlots)` is returning the same value in `tableSlots` property. 
[image: tableSlots property result]

> I see also, that issue occurs when Vue component is
> used in page view called like 
> `@{ Html.RenderAction(...)}` in .net mvc project.

So, now. What is the cause of this issue that the content (in that case - buttons) are not compiled/visible?

Comment: That should work; something else is the issue. Can you provide more information, or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weeell. I found a workaround!

> Necessary was move filling the fields from `mounted` to
> `created`.